# Segmentation fault in unix ,but working fine in Windows

Tags: c++, unix, static

```
classa classa::_var

classa::classa() {

}
```

`_var` is a static object for `classa`.At the  time of loading of dll ,the control comes to static object initializati.At this point the control goes to constructor and  after executing code inside constructor it breaks with Segmentation fault.
This is working fine in windows,only in unix I am getting this problem.

On checking the value of `_var` using print command from dbx debugger it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: if you are unfamiliar with SO, read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: It will be easier for us to help if you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please post more complete code for the class in question.  My hunch though is that you are somehow depending on the order in which multiple static variables are initialized, which you can't do (the compiler is free to run their constructors in any order if they're independent variables).  A possible work-around is to force static variables to be initialized just-in-time, e.g. replace `classa classa::_var;` with `classa& getVar() { static classa x; return x; }` (so that the function must be called in order to initialize the value, and it won't be initialized until that time).

Comment: Hello Kevin .Thanks for reply.The object is private member and there is no code inside the constructor.I could not understand how I am going to use the getVar() method.Is it going to be a static method?